# Z3 formula fails syntatic check

Tags: z3

The following SMT formula fails syntactic check at rise4fun site when x13 is replaced by av5 in the line with arrow.

```
(set-info :status unknown) 
;(set-logic QF_BV) 
(declare-fun in3 () (_ BitVec 16)) 
(assert 
(let ((x8 ((_ zero_extend 16) in3))) 
(let ((x13 (ite (not (= x8 (_ bv00000000 32))) (_ bv00045069 32) (_ bv00000174 32)))) 
(let ((av5 (= x13 (_ bv00045069 32)))) 
(= x13 (_ bv4294967295 32)))))) <--------- 
(assert true) 
(check-sat)
```

The error message is

*Z3(8, 26): ERROR: invalid function application, sort mismatch on argument at position 2*

Any idea what I might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give a link to your rise4fun example?

Comment: The permalink to the example is http://rise4fun.com/Z3/on1pl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version are you using? I can't reproduce this problem using version 4.3.x nor using the unstable (working-in-progress) branch. In both cases, I get `unsat`. I also get `unsat` on [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/gO29).

Comment: I'm currently trying it out on rise4fun.  And, I encounter the same problem at both http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide and rise4fun.com/Z3/on1pl.

BTW, rise4fun is ideal in scratch pad mode.  It reminds me IPython notebook.  I think it would help to extend rise4fun with notebook support.  Try out the notebooks at http://nbviewer.ipython.org/.

Comment: In the link:  rise4fun.com/Z3/on1pl, av5 is a Boolean. That is why you get a "sort mismatch" at `(= av5 (_ bv4294967295 32))`.

Comment: Regarding Rise4Fun, I agree it would be great to have notebook-like support. It would be great also if we could create tutorials and content online using a wiki-based interface.

Comment: After using general programming languages, it is rather strange to deal with bit extensions in Z3 :)  Anyways, now I know the issue and how to address it.  Thanks